# how to find a good wireless PowerPoint controller device?

Tags: wireless-networking, microsoft-powerpoint, iwork-keynote

I'm looking for a wireless gadget to advance PowerPoint slides, and would also work with Keynote or whatever on a Mac.

Sub-questions:

(a) What are these things called, so I can search for them.

(b) What is a reasonable price point - the cheap ones seem to be under $20, and name brand seem to be $40 or $50. Do the cheap no-name devices work?

(c) Specific device recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

1. My colleagues and I have always called them clickers.
2. We've had good luck with the cheapies.
3. If you're on a Mac with IR, why not just [use](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/forum-replies-archive.cfm/516332.html) the [Apple Remote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Remote)?

Comment: Thanks! To clarify: currently I have a ThinkPad, which is an awful piece of garbage. When the time comes, I'd like to replace it with a Mac laptop. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the Apple Remote app for the iPhone/iPod if you have one. Not bad for 59p

Answer (score 0):

These devices are called "[wireless presenters](http://www.google.com/search?hl=enq=wireless+presenter)". I can recommend the Kensington Devices, especially [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FPGP4U) one. 
You should pay attention at the transmission used: Infrared only works if you point the device directly onto the receiver. Also a laser-pointer is very helpful.
All those devices normaly work on windows, mac and linux because they emulate a ordinary keyboard, so you dont have to install drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Or just use a wireless mouse and click in midair. Much simpler and more universal, especially with the large number of laptops around nowadays. You might even have one already.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for "RF Presenters" too.

I'm using [this one](http://www.dealextreme.com/details.dx/sku.15067) on Windows and Linux, it works like a charm. No brand, but really cheap and it uses 2 AA's - so, if you forgot to charge and have to do presentation ASAP, just buy more batteries.